# How to access remote server with local phpMyAdmin client?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Assuming there is a remote server and I have phpMyAdmin client installed localy on my computer. How can I access this server and manage it via phpMyAdmin client? Is that possible?

Comment: you can also install the `phpmyadmin` docker image locally and connect to your remote MySQL server. more details at [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin): `docker run --name myadmin -d -e PMA_HOST=<REMOTE_DB_HOST> -e PMA_PORT=<REMOTE_DB_PORT> -p 8080:80 phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin`

Answer (score 247):

Just add below lines to your `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` file in the bottom:

```php
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'HostName:port'; //provide hostname and port if other than default
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'userName';   //user name for your remote server
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'Password';  //password
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';       // keep it as config
```

You will get  `Current Server:` drop down  with both `127.0.0.1` and one what you have provided with `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']` can switch between the servers.

More Details: http://sforsuresh.in/access-remote-mysql-server-using-local-phpmyadmin/

Comment: The `$i++` is an important point as this will not make us lose the database connection with the default `localhost`.

Comment: I also had to follow the steps in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql) post after setting it up in phpMyAdmin to make it work.

Comment: `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` is the correct file to be changed

Comment: If anyone is working on Apple system then the `config.inc.php` file is located at  `Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` file.

Answer (score 34):

It is certainly possible to access a remote MySQL server from a local instance of phpMyAdmin, as the other answers have pointed out. And for that to work, you have to [configure the remote server's MySQL server to accept remote connections](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html), and allow traffic through the firewall for the port number that MySQL is listening to. I prefer a slightly different solution involving [SSH Tunnelling](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html).

The following command will set up an SSH tunnel which will forward all requests made to port 3307 from your local machine to port 3306 on the remote machine:

```
ssh -NL 3307:localhost:3306 root@REMOTE_HOST
```

When prompted, you should enter the password for the root user on the remote machine. This will open the tunnel. If you want to run this in the background, you'll need to add the `-f` argument, and set up [Passwordless SSH](https://degreesofzero.com/article/passwordless-ssh-on-linux.html) between your local machine and the remote machine.

After you've got the SSH tunnel working, you can add the remote server to the servers list in your local phpMyAdmin by modifying the `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` file. Add the following to the end of the file:

```php
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose']       = 'Remote Server 1'; // Change this to whatever you like.
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '3307';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = FALSE;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'cookie';
$i++;
```

I wrote a more in-depth [blog post](https://degreesofzero.com/article/manage-remote-mysql-servers-with-local-phpmyadmin.html) about exactly this, in case you need additional help.

Comment: I think this is the secure solution. Opening up mySQL to direct remote access is generally considered a poor security practice if it's not absolutely necessary.

Comment: c.hill's answer is not quite right. Please note: The bind address must be set to the loop back address in the mysql my.cnf file.

Comment: No need to be root on the remote host. the bridge works perfectly, thanks! I'm not so sure about config, though, prefer Suresh Kamrushi's answer. `$++` should definitely be first line, not last, at least for my default phpmyadmin.conf.

Comment: The Best Solution!

Comment: You can access to a databaseServer only accessible from Server, which in turn you need to go through a jumpServer: `ssh -v -N -L 3306:databaseServer:3306 -J jumpUsername@jumpServer usrname@Server`. Test on your host with `nc -zv localhost 3306`. Consider using something like DBeaver instead of phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 28):

It can be done, but you need to change the phpMyAdmin configuration, read this post:
http://www.danielmois.com/article/Manage_remote_databases_from_localhost_with_phpMyAdmin

If for any reason the link dies, you can use the following steps:

- Find phpMyAdmin's configuration file, called `config.inc.php`
- Find the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']` variable, and set it to the IP or hostname of your remote server
- Find the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']` variable, and set it to the remote mysql port. Usually this is `3306`
- Find the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']` and `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']` variables and set these to your username and password for the remote server

Without proper server configuration, the connection may be slower than a local connection for example, it's would probably be slightly faster to use IP addresses instead of host names to avoid the server having to look up the IP address from the hostname.

In addition, remember that your remote database's username and password is stored in plain text when you connect like this, so you should take steps to ensure that no one can access this config file. Alternatively, you can leave the username and password variables empty to be prompted to enter them each time you log in, which is a lot more secure.

Comment: You also need to have the firewall on the database instance allow the traffic, and a user on the DB server with privileges for remote access.

Comment: May I ask a question here? As I newbie I am curious what form should the link have I want to enter in browser in order to access a database via phpMyAdmin that is installed on a server of my client who hosts a website himself.

Answer (score 13):

Follow this blog post. You can do it very easily. 
https://wadsashika.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/manage-remote-mysql-database-locally-using-phpmyadmin/

The file **config.inc.php** contains the configuration settings for your phpMyAdmin installation. It uses an array to store sets of config options for every server it can connect to and by default there is only one, your own machine, or localhost. In order to connect to another server, you would have to add another set of config options to the config array. You have to edit this configuration file.

First open **config.inc.php** file held in **phpMyAdmin** folder. In **wamp** server, you can find it in **wamp\apps\phpmyadmin** folder. Then add following part to that file.

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = 'hostname/Ip Adress';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = FALSE;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'username';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'password';
```

Let’s see what is the meaning of this variables.

```
$i++ :- Incrementing variable for each server
$cfg[‘Servers’][$i][‘host’] :- Server host name or IP adress
$cfg[‘Servers’][$i][‘port’] :- MySQL port (Leave a blank for default port. Default MySQL port is 3306)
$cfg[‘Servers’][$i][‘socket’] :- Path to the socket (Leave a blank for default socket)
$cfg[‘Servers’][$i][‘connect_type’] :- How to connect to MySQL server (‘tcp’ or ‘socket’)
$cfg[‘Servers’][$i][‘extension’] :- php MySQL extension to use (‘mysql’ or ‘msqli’)
$cfg[‘Servers’][$i][‘compress’] :- Use compressed protocol for the MySQL connection (requires PHP >= 4.3.0)
$cfg[‘Servers’][$i][‘auth_type’] :- Method of Authentication
$cfg[‘Servers’][$i][‘username’] :- Username to the MySQL database in remote server
$cfg[‘Servers’][$i][‘password’] :- Password to the MySQL database int he remote server
```

After adding this configuration part, restart you server and now your phpMyAdmin home page will change and it will show a field to select the server.

Now you can select you server and access your remote database by entering username and password for that database.

Comment: could please be more accurate and explain more about your answer. link answers are good but the may be unreachable if the link corrupts for any reason.

Answer (score 9):

As stated in answer [c.hill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23270907/3589481) answer, if you want a **secure solution** I would advise to open an SSH tunnel to your server.

Here is the way to do it for **Windows** users:

1. Download Plink and Putty from the [Putty website](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) and place the files in the folder of your choice (In my example `C:\Putty`)
2. Open the Windows console and cd to Plink folder:
   `cd C:\Putty`
3. Open the SSH tunnel and redirect to the port 3307:

   `plink -L 3307:localhost:3306 username@server_ip -i path_to_your_private_key.ppk`

Where:

- 3307 is the local port you want to redirect to
- localhost is the address of the MySQL DB on the remote server (localhost by default)
- 3306 is the port use for PhpMyAdmin on the remote server (3306 by default)

Finally you can setup PhpMyAdmin:

4. Add the remote server to your local PhpMyAdmin configuration by adding the following line at the end of **config.inc.php**

Lines to add:

```
$i++;   
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose']          = 'Remote Dev server';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']             = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']             = '3307';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']     = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']        = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']         = FALSE;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']        = 'cookie';
```

5. You should be able to connect now at `http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin`

If you do not want to open the console each time you need to connect to your remote server, just create a batch file (by saving the 2 command lines in a .bat file).

Answer (score 7):

You can set in the  config.inc.php file of your phpMyAdmin installation.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '';
```

Answer (score 6):

I would have added this as a comment, but my reputation is not yet high enough.

Under version 4.5.4.1deb2ubuntu2, and I am guessing any other versions 4.5.x or newer.  There is no need to modify the config.inc.php file at all.  Instead go one more directory down conf.d.

Create a new file with the '.php' extension and add the lines.  This is a better modularized approach and isolates each remote database server access information.

Answer (score 3):

**In Ubuntu**

Just you need to modify a single file in PHPMyAdmin folder i.e. “config.inc.php”.Just add below lines to your “config.inc.php”.

File location : `/var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` OR 
                `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`

Maybe you don't have the permission for editing that file, just give the permission using this command

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

OR (in different systems you may have to check with these two locations)

```
sudo chmod 777 /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

Then copy and paste the code in your `config.inc.php` file

```
    $i++;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'cookie';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'Database Server 2';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '34.12.123.31';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = false;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

And make the appropriate changes with your server details

Answer (score 3):

Locate the file **libraries/config.default.php**

then find  **$cfg['AllowArbitraryServer'] = false;**

then set It to **true**

note:

on ubuntu the file in the path **/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/config.default.php**

then you will find a new filed name SERVER in the main  PHPMyAdmin page, you can add any IP or localhost for the local database.

Answer (score 2):

Go to file \phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php at the very bottom, change the hosting details such as host, username, password etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1** ( for multiserver )

First , lets make a backup of original config.

```
sudo cp /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php      ~/
```

Now in **/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/examples/** you will see a file **config.manyhosts.inc.php**. Just copy in to **/etc/phpmyadmin/**
using command bellow:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/examples/config.manyhosts.inc.php \
        /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

Edit the **config.inc.php**

```
sudo nano /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

Search for :

```
$hosts = array (
    "foo.example.com",
    "bar.example.com",
    "baz.example.com",
    "quux.example.com",
);
```

And add your ip or hostname array save ( in nano CTRL+X press Y ) and exit . Done

**Method 2** ( single server )
Edit the **config.inc.php**

```
sudo nano /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

Search for :

```
/* Server parameters */
if (empty($dbserver)) $dbserver = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = $dbserver;

if (!empty($dbport) || $dbserver != 'localhost') {
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = $dbport;
}
```

And replace with:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '192.168.1.100';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
```

Remeber to replace **192.168.1.100**  with your own mysql ip server.

Sorry for my bad English ( google translate have the blame :D )

Answer (score 0):

In Windows with Wamp Server Installed you may find the configuration file

```
C:\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin4.8.4\config.inc.php
```

Change the bolow line as appropriate

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = 3306;//$wampConf['mysqlPortUsed'];
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

When developing with no password set, you might not get access to the server due to the absence of the `AllowNoPassword` field. To prevent this, open `config.inc.php` and add this block with `AllowNoPassword` set to `true` right bellow `$i = 0` variable:

```
$i++;

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']            = 'your_server_ip';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']            = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']          = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']    = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']       = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']        = FALSE;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']       = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']            = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']        = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Answer (score -1):

Delete complete entries of `/etc/http/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf`

And below entires in above file,

```css
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       #ADD following line:
       Require all granted
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     #CHANGE following 2 lines:
     Order Allow,Deny
     Allow from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Then,

run below command in MySQL prompt,

`GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'root@<password>'`

`GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root@<password>'`

For reference: [Allow IP to Access Secured PhpMyAdmin](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/allow-all-ip-to-access-my-secured-phpmyadmin)