# Second server for phpMyAdmin points to main.php instead of index.php

Tags: phpmyadmin, mamp

I followed [How to access remote server with local phpMyAdmin client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801573/how-to-access-remote-server-with-local-phpmyadmin-client) to add a second server to phpMyAdmin:

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = 'internal.host.name'; // MySQL hostname or IP address
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '';          // MySQL port - leave blank for default port
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '';          // Path to the socket - leave blank for default socket
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';       // How to connect to MySQL server ('tcp' or 'socket')
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysql';     // The php MySQL extension to use ('mysql' or 'mysqli')
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = FALSE;       // Use compressed protocol for the MySQL connection
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';    // Authentication method (config, http or cookie based)?
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']              = 'the user name';      // MySQL user
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'secret';          // MySQL password
```

I get a drop down with the two configured servers. As soon I select *internal.host.name* the browser says:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /phpMyAdmin/main.php was not found on this server.
```

The problem is, that the URL should end in `index.php` and not `main.php`. How can I change that?

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version? What happens if you remove/comment out one server, try to log in and view your databases, then log out and edit so only the second server is used, and log in again? Or to put it another way, does it work correctly on both servers when they are configured as the only server?

Answer (score 7):

You have to edit `MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php`, which is the same file you modified to add the second server, so that you change this:

```
$cfg['DefaultTabServer'] = 'main.php';
```

to this:

```
$cfg['DefaultTabServer'] = 'index.php';
```