# How can I export mysql database without cpanel access

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would like to export mysql database from one hosting to another but I don't have the cpanel username & password, therefore I can't do it through phpMyadmin. How can I export the database?

I have the database username & password. Also FTP access

Comment: You can install phpmyadmin on your local machine and configure it to connect to your database on the server, then export the database.

Comment: HeidiSQL may be helpful. [link](http://www.heidisql.com/)

Comment: Aren't the `FTP` access infos the same as `cPanel`'s?

Comment: Use SSH and the command line :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use mysqldump command line tool (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) with `--opt --single-transaction` switches. Presuming you have username & password and grants on database allowing you to connect from some other IP. You can install these tools on your local machine - they are part of `mysql-client-x.x` package.

Answer (score 0):

Is the database for a website to which you have back-end access? Most CMS systems offer a module where you can access and download the site's database via the site's admin area (EG ART Adminer in Joomla).

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSH access:

```
// SSH into the server
> ssh -p 22 user@ip

// create your backup
mysqldump --user=username --password="password" --host=localhost database_name > /path/to/export.sql
```

If you don't have SSH access, try executing the above dump with PHP's [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).

If you don't have the privileges to use the functions above, you can configure a local installation of PHPMyAdmin to use an external server as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801573/how-to-access-remote-server-with-local-phpmyadmin-client).