# Access mysql server installed in another server through phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two servers. server1 and server2.

phpmyadmin is installed on server1(centos7).

mysql server is installed on server2(centos7).

I want to connect to server2 mysql through server1 phpyadmin 
using server1 phpmyadmin url
Forexample : http://server1.ip/phpmyadmin/

But when i try to login using server2 mysql root credentials. I am getting cannot login to mysql server error.
[image]

my config.inc.php file located at /etc/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php has entries as shown below.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = '192.xxx.x.xxx';//server2 ip address 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '3306';          
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '';          
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';       
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysqli';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = FALSE;       
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']   = '';          

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']   = '';          


$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'cookie';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'root';          
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'xxxx';          
//xxxx server2 mysql root password
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['only_db']       = '';
```

What am i missing? Please help.

Btw i have enabled remote connections to server2 mysql.
I am also able to connect to server2 mysql using mysql workbench.

I am also able to connect to server2 mysql using phpmyadmin installed locally.

I am not able to connect to server2 mysql using phpmyadmin installed on server1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801573/how-to-access-remote-server-with-local-phpmyadmin-client This might help you

Comment: I am able to connect to server2 mysql using my local phpmyadmin. but i am not able to connect using server1 phpmyadmin.