# How to connect mysql when deploying node app on heroku

Tags: mysql, reactjs, heroku, phpmyadmin, mysql2

I have already deployed my node app with heroku which is working fine with my local phpmyadmin database but how can i use it without starting mysql on local machine.
OR how to connect my node app deployed in heroku with phpmyadmin(mysql2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access remote server with local phpMyAdmin client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801573/how-to-access-remote-server-with-local-phpmyadmin-client)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use local MySQL database in the production app which you have deployed in a hosting provider in this case Heroku.

You could create a remote MySQL database resource from providers like [db4free.net](https://www.db4free.net/).

Update your code to use database credentials of the remote database and start using it.

Note Heroku also provides a MySQL service. You could set up your database there too if you need.

Comment: i have cpanel access to my one more website 

this is my config file please assist
const sequelize = new Sequelize("anandshe_node", "****", "****", {
  host: 'anandshendage.com',
  port : 2083,
  dialect: 'mysql',
  operatorsAliases: false
});