# Database is in localhost of server. How to connect with it remotely

Tags: mysql

My hosting site provided me phpMyAdmin on server's localhost. How to connect remotely to MySql using remote tool as Session Manager or MySql Workbench.
When i work database in my website i use hostname as localhost. So question is what to fill in hostname in workbench. I already tried hosting site ip address, but couldnt connect with database.
[A screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9WFD.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access remote server with local phpMyAdmin client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801573/how-to-access-remote-server-with-local-phpmyadmin-client)

Comment: Did you check that your server is allowing this way to connect DB?

Comment: where to look for it. I am new in programming

Answer (score 0):

From the [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9WFD.png), you shared I can see you are using HeidiSQL software to connect with a remote MySQL server. Hostname/IP should be your hosting IP address provided by your hosting provider. You need to verify the port where your MySQL is running. Here you have set 3306 which is the default port. It could run on a different port. In the User and Password fields, you should use your username and password to login into your hosting server.