# Deploy Python Flask app with MySQL and phpmyadmin

Tags: python, mysql, flask, deployment, phpmyadmin

I've done an app in Python on Windows that took data from an API, make some calculations, and store the results in MySQL database. I like retrieving data and make some SQL requests directly from phpmyadmin.
I took a droplet in Digital Ocean, but it is quite hard for me.

I would like to find an alternative, as I knew with web hosting when I deployed websites 10 years ago, where you have just to deploy your app from GitHub and only manage key parameters (URI, username, password, database name) in your source code.
Have you got some tips?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Heroku: https://www.heroku.com/.
I once used a Flask App with a SQL DB there. Simply import your DB to ClearDB. It all worked quite well. You also can connect it to your github so that it automatically deploys new versions.
If you really need phpmyadmin, I would not install it in the cloud, but instead run phpmyadmin locally and connect to the remote db as described here [How to access remote server with local phpMyAdmin client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801573/how-to-access-remote-server-with-local-phpmyadmin-client/22092539#22092539).
Btw it is not very safe to store URI, username, password, database name in source code. They do not belong in the source code, but should be stored as environment variables https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: Thanks for your tip.
I discovered Digital Ocean App Platform that does pretty the same than Heroku.
And as you advice, I will use environment variables.