# Symfony2 ClearDB configuration on Heroku

Tags: symfony, heroku

Can anyone explicitly tell me how to connect a my symfony2 App to ClearDB on heroku?

I got the connection string on heroku by typing

```
$ heroku config
```

but when i put the results on my parameters.yml i get a SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you read something like this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-symfony2?

Comment: Yes and they only have a none DB powered application if you read the whole page

Comment: And read this question and answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822313/remote-connect-to-cleardb-heroku-database, you need the user, password and host set in your parameters.yml

Comment: http://www.christophh.net/2013/10/19/sylius-on-heroku/ has some info, never used it so not sure about it's quality.

Comment: Please read and understand my question clearly. I already have the connection string and have put the settings on my parameters.yml without much success.

I also tried to add the settings to environment variables like this

$ heroku config:set SYMFONY__SECRET=ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
$ heroku config:set SYMFONY__DATABASE_USER=heroku_db_user

without success either

Comment: I wish there was someone out there who's done this before

Comment: I would like to know the anwser also.

Comment: I'll put the answer below in a few minutes

Comment: 1. Put your connection parameters in parameters.php instead of parameters.yml

Answer (score 2):

This will help anyone else stuck like I was:

1. Put your connection parameters in `parameters.php` instead of `parameters.yml` as below

   ```
   <?php

   // Using ClearDB for mysql database
   $db = parse_url($_ENV['CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL']); 
   $container->setParameter('database_driver', 'pdo_mysql'); 
   $container->setParameter('database_host', $db['host']); 
   $container->setParameter('database_port', '~');
   $container->setParameter('database_name', trim($db['path'], '/')); 
   $container->setParameter('database_user', $db['user']); 
   $container->setParameter('database_password', $db['pass']);

   // Using Mandrill to send email
   $container->setParameter('mailer_transport', 'smtp');
   $container->setParameter('mailer_host', 'smtp.mandrillapp.com');
   $container->setParameter('mailer_user', $_ENV['MANDRILL_USERNAME']);
   $container->setParameter('mailer_password', $_ENV['MANDRILL_APIKEY']);

   // Other settings
   $container->setParameter('locale', 'en');
   $container->setParameter('secret', 'your_secret');

   ?>
   ```
2. Include `parameters.php` in your config file:

   ```
   imports: - { resource: parameters.php}
   ```