# ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host, Playframework & clearDB

Tags: mysql, scala, heroku, playframework, cleardb

I created the clear db for heroku app.

```
heroku config --app APP_NAME
```

I get these:

```
APPLICATION_SECRET:   ABCDEFG;

CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL: mysql://aaa:bbb@ccc.cleardb.net/heroku_ddd?reconnect=true
DATABASE_URL:         mysql://aaa:bbb@ccc.cleardb.net/heroku_ddd?reconnect=true
```

And I ran:

```
mysql -h aaa:bbb@ccc.cleardb.net -u ddd -p
```

And it requires the password that I don't know what it is.
After I pushed "Enter", it says:

```
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'aaa:bbb@ccc.cleardb.net' (0)
```

In the Play! application.conf file, the settings about the db are:

```
default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
default.url = "jdbc:mysql://aaa:bbb@ccc.cleardb.net/heroku_ddd?reconnect=true&characterEncoding=UTF8"
```

How should I fix the error, connect to the cleardb and start doing some sql expressions?

Comment: You get this error from the `mysql` CLI but not from your app, correct?

Comment: in your demo example, in the CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL variable, the server host part is between the @ and the slash: "ccc.cleardb.net". check this post for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822313/remote-connect-to-cleardb-heroku-database