# Wordpress Duplicator Installer on Heroku

Tags: php, wordpress, heroku

I've built out a wordpress website locally and now I'd like to deploy it from localhost to an actual web address hosted on Heroku.

I've created a new sql database on my newly created Heroku site and am using the Wordpress Duplicator plugin to transfer everything over.

I've pushed all my files onto heroku master, and I've installed the Duplicator installer.php and .zip files.

However, when I actually try connecting to my Heroku data from the installer, it pauses for a while and gives the following error.

"An error occurred while testing the database connection!  Contact your server admin to make sure the connection inputs are correct!"

Am I missing something in regard to connecting to Heroku databases externally? What's the best way to get wordpress up on Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the SQL connection string for your app deployed on heroku is very definitely not localhost. In particular:

- If you've been using mysql for local deployment, you will need the [ClearDB plugin added to heroku](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/cleardb); instructions on how to optain the endpoint for the ClearDB database are here: [Remote connect to clearDB heroku database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822313/remote-connect-to-cleardb-heroku-database)
- If you're planning to [deploy wordpress using the postgresql database](https://wordpress.org/plugins/postgresql-for-wordpress/), you need to add the postgresql add-on, and configure wordpress to it. There's already instructions, and a full repo for [wordpress-heroku](https://github.com/mhoofman/wordpress-heroku) that you may peruse

Hope this helps.