# How to make a backup of a Heroku ClearDB MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, heroku, cleardb

I have a PHP Heroku app running, which uses a ClearDB MySQL database. I need to make backups of the database. I've been searching how to do it but I can't find it. Thanks.

Comment: `mysqldump` works fine on a remote host. You can get the credentials from `heroku config`.

Comment: This can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822313/remote-connect-to-cleardb-heroku-database

Comment: @ceejayoz And how can I run mysqldump on the server? I've tried `heroku run mysqldump` but it says `command not found`.

Comment: You'd run it on your local computer, with the [`--host` parameter](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_host) to work with the remote connection. Use `heroku config` to look up the host, username, password, etc.

Comment: Ah, I understand. It makes sense. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you can do:

```
mysqldump -u<username> <DATABASENAME> --host=<host-url> -p > <afilename>
```

It will look something like

```
mysqldump -ub13cXXXXX heroku_6a343XXXXX --host=eu-cdbr-west-03.cleardb.net -p > mydbdump.sql
```

And it will ask your password.